# What are bonus sources? (of oil in my case)

Tags: civilization-6

I have 2 oils from bonus sources. What are bonus sources?

No city states at all seem to have oil. I can find nothing on Google. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The only possible explanation I can fathom is that you have revealed Oil but haven't improved it yet and are suzerain of Hattusa. Check it's unique bonus which will grant you two of each strategic resource you have revealed but not improved.